# No way to choose wayland in GDM using UbuntuGNOME 17.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, gdm, wayland

I am trying to get wayland running using UbuntuGnome 17.04 with nvidia-381 installed using the graphics-drivers ppa and a Geforce 1050TI card. 
Using older Ubuntu versions I was able to select between Weston, Wayland and/or Kodi, if installed. Using 17.04 I may only choose between Gnome and Gnome Classic. I installed all packages needed, as far as i know, as well as their recommended packages, synaptic is showing. Is there any package I need to install or reinstall or reconfigure?

Using no nvidia drivers, the regular nouveau and xorg drivers or the xorg-edgers or oibaf ppa lets me run the system, but without having any hardware acceleration. As well as no option to choose wayland in GDM. I just may choose Kodi then...

The installed packages on my machine for using wayland are:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (highly experimental [according to nVIDIA](https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/381.22/README/kms.html), but actually worked in my case)

```
sudo modprobe -r nvidia-drm 
sudo modprobe nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried a lot of workarounds but nvidia drivers don't support wayland session using gdm and gnome. The only way to get it running was to set `modeset=1` with `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` using nvidia-381. After `sudo update-initramfs -u` and rebooting I was able to log into wayland, but that workaround breaks something as I was not able to run anything as root or superuser. I hope there will be a fix soon. The only way to set it back is to switch to tty and using nano instead of gedit to set the entries to their defaults.

Comment: This worked for me! Wayland seems a little rough around the edges, a little slower than x at the moment but everything seems to work.

Comment: Setting modeset=1 breaks the whole system for me: gnome session does not start. I have nvidia GTX 980 Ti, nvidia-381, Ubuntu 17.04