# per display scaling (HiDPI) not working for some reason

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, scaling

Scaling works fine when using the "**Single Display**" mode.

But when I try to switch over to "**Join Displays**" I don't get the "**Apply**" button when setting 2nd monitor to 4k and 200% scaling and other monitor to 1080p and no scaling.

There is a apply button when I select 100% scaling, which is weird.

GPU: Nvidia GTX 1080

Drivers: NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.90 from nvidia-384 (Proprietary, tested)

Screenshots

Single Display mode with 200% scaling working fine:

[image: Single Display mode with 200% scaling working fine]

With 1080 and 4k on at the same time, unable to select 200%:

[image: With 1080 and 4k on at the same time, unable to select 200%]

Comment: Bumb.. Anyone know what to do..? :/

Answer (score 4):

It seems different scaling on different monitors only works on Wayland display server. But nvidia driver default settings prevents Wayland to run, so old Xorg display manager is used.

Solutions:

1) You can use opensource nouveau driver instead of nvidia driver. It works slower but scaling works fine.

2) You can change nvidia drivers setting: Add `modeset=1` option to `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` file
so last line should look like
`options nvidia_384_drm modeset=1`

Next run `$ sudo update-initramfs -u` and restart.

(source: [No way to choose wayland in GDM using UbuntuGNOME 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907727/no-way-to-choose-wayland-in-gdm-using-ubuntugnome-17-04))

Also you can enable fractional scaling (like 150%): 
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux

Solutions 2 works for me on NVidia 960. my 4k monitor scaling=150% while 1080p monitor scaling=100%.